# Example of "Impure" Component

Tags: reactjs

The React docs section on [component specifications](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html) discusses keeping the `render` method "pure" and explains what that means.

I've run into a few situations where React throws an error because I am doing something improper in `render`, but would like to know if there are situations where a component could be "impure" but not trigger an error.

Could anyone provide an example of a component that does one or more of the following without throwing an error in React?

- modifies component state in `render` (or anywhere else it shouldn't)
- reads from or writes to the DOM when it shouldn't
- doesn't return the same result each time it's invoked/rendered
- (possibly the same as previous): doesn't render the same DOM for the same props and state

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pretend these are all in render.

#### "modifies component state in render (or anywhere else it shouldn't)"

```js
this.state.foo = whatever;
```

#### "reads from or writes to the DOM when it shouldn't"

```js
if (this.isMounted()) { this.getDOMNode().textContent = whatever };
document.querySelector('title').textContent = whatever;
```

#### "doesn't return the same result each time it's invoked/rendered"

```js
return <div>{Math.random()}</div>
```

#### "(possibly the same as previous): doesn't render the same DOM for the same props and state"

```js
if (new Date().getHours()>=9 && new Date().getHours()<=12+5) {
    return <div>{this.props.fortune}</div>
}
else {
    return <div>I'm off the clock</div>
}
```

---

You mentioned the last example specifically in a comment, so the correct way to deal with time is to get the time in getInitialState, and then set a timeout in componentDidMount for when the time changing will affect rendering, and setState there.  This way your UI stays in sync with the world.

A naive solution is to just setInterval to a few seconds, which is fine until you have time to optimize it.  The real solution here would be something like

```js
var now = Date.now(),
    closing = new Date(); closing.setHours(12+5, 0, 0, 0),
    opening = new Date(); opening.setHours(9, 0, 0, 0), delay; 

// past closing
if (now > closing || now < opening) {
    if (opening < now) {
        opening.setHours(9+24);
    }
    delay = opening - now;
}
// currently open
else {
    delay = closing - now;
}
setTimeout(delay, updateStateWithTime);
```

And like any state change over time, mixins are often a good way to abstract and reuse.

Comment: Great answer, thank you. The last example is the one I'm most interested in -- I have been guilty of that one and suspected it was an antipattern.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. Really enjoying your book btw